# Why is $g(x)=0$ a.s. if $p(x | \theta)$ is a density and $\int_0^\infty g(x) p(x | \theta) dx = E[g(x)] = 0$ for all $\theta$?

Tags: complete-statistics

I am trying to prove that a statistic $T$ is complete, where $T \sim \text{Gamma}(n, e^\theta)$. I am stuck at deducing that $g(T)$ must be zero almost surely, just by looking at the expectation:
$$ E[g(T)] = \int_0^\infty g(t) t^{n-1} e^{-te^\theta} \frac{e^{-n \theta}}{\Gamma(n)} dt= 0 $$
The above shoulld imply that $g(t)=0$ almost surely.

Why is $g(t)=0$ if $$\int_0^\infty g(t) t^{n-1} e^{-te^\theta} dt = 0$$ for all $\theta$? I know that $t^{n-1} e^{-te^\theta}$ is a positive function, but $g(t)$ does not have to be? Is it because the integral must be zero for the whole gamma family?

Comment: It might help to recognize your last integral as the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition) of the function $t\to g(t)t^{n-1}$ evaluated at $e^\theta\gt 0.$

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I was not familiar with Laplace transformations, and I managed to find an answer here, but, I think I'm out of my league..
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47507/if-int-0-infty-e-lambda-tft-rm-dt-0-for-all-lambda-0-then-f